# Calling C from Express.js?

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, web

What are best practices for doing this?

I have a program written in C that does some number crunching. This needs to be used by a site  which is written using Express.js via Node. What's the best way to interface the two together?

Do I do something like this in JavaScript

```
exec("./foo -parameters here")
```

or is there a better way to go forward?